# AS3: Increase size of scroll bar

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, scroll, touch

This my be a really simple question but I have googled so hard looking for an answer. I have a datagrid which displays a long list of information. Its an iOS app so the input is touch and the scroll bar is tiny. How can I increase its size for easier use?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Feathers is as3 solution to mobile ui :  http://feathersui.com

Answer (score 0):

These scrollbars can be targeted by `DataGridInstance.verticalScrollBar` and `DataGridInstance.horizontalScrollBar`. These are actually ScrollBar instances so you can use the `.setSize()` method or `.width` and `.height` setters to resize these.

However, [**the documentation**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f57.html) indicates:

> ***Note:** If you use the **`setSize()`** method, you can change only the width of a horizontal scroll bar or the height of a vertical scroll bar. At the time of authoring you can set the height of a horizontal scroll bar or the width of a vertical scroll bar, but the values will be reset when the movie is published. Only the dimension of a scroll bar that corresponds to its length can be changed.*

So I'm afraid it's not an option with the built-in component.

Comment: @JaredBrandjes I was not suggesting anything, actually. I was just passing you the official information that indicates it's not possible with the built-in component [unfortunately].

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
dataGrid.scroller.verticalScrollBar.scaleX = 2;
```